# What is custom operators precedence?

Tags: python

When you have some overridden operators in Python what are their order-resolving rules? Are they they always the same as for original operators like here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?#operator-precedence? And if yes, can that be changed somehow?

Comment: Yes, order is the same, why would you want to change it?

Comment: To make the code harder to interpret by someone else I guess?

Comment: First part of the question was practical, a second one academical. You never know about some tricky use-cases.